# Get aliased class name after a class_alias

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to get the aliased class name after a class_alias? If not, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [`get_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
class foo { }

class_alias('foo', 'bar');

$a = new foo;
$b = new bar;

var_dump( get_class( $a ) );
var_dump( get_class( $b ) );
```

outputs

```
string(3) "foo"
string(3) "foo"
```

Comment: Oh, I upvoted but it doesn't work. Actually, I would like to get 'bar' instead. Is this possible?

Comment: Ah, that's another question then ;-) "How to get the aliased classname." I don't know if that's possible, I don't think so: the new name is just a synonym for the original name. The classes are exactly equivalent. Even with [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) the results are the same.